# C# Regex capturing groups

Tags: c#, regex

Trying to wrap my head around `Regex capturing groups` and having a little trouble.

I have some strings for which I want to capture groups for:

```
@msg=hello;name=test 1 // Groups: msg = hello, name = test, rest = 1 
@msg=hi 2 // Groups: msg = hello, name = null, rest = 2
@name=tt 3 // Groups: msg = null, name = tt, rest = 3
```

I have the following `regex`:

```
msg=(?P<msg>[^;]+)?.*name=(?P<name>[^;]+)?\s(?P<rest>.*)
```

Which works fine for the first row, **but not the second or third**. Any idea how I can make it work for them too? I tried putting some `()?` around the capturing groups to no avail:

```
// Below gets me weird results
(msg=(?P<msg>[^;]+)?)?.*(name=(?P<name>[^;]+)?)?\s((?P<rest>.*))?
```

Thanks.

Comment: There's some great Regex testers out there that should be able to help you. Play around with regexr.com until you find what you're looking for, you can learn a lot while doing it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a more strict token rather than negation, using optional non-capturing groups:

```
@(?:msg=(?<msg>\w+);?)?(?:name=(?<name>\w+))?\s*(?<rest>.*)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oY6fR6/3)

Comment: I'm very firm with Regex but I didn't see the construct `(?P<` for named groups in C# before. What's the difference between `(?P<xxx>` and `(?<xxx>`? [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't know this pattern. Btw: This pattern doesn't work in C#. Are we really talking about C#?

Comment: Sorry, it was intended to be reduced before but it saved the post with the original named group.